# Delphi ORD function not returning expected value

Tags: delphi

I have 2 functions, one to encrypt and the other to de-crypt a string, that use the Ord() function. It works great except with extended Ascii codes.

If I use the letter ê (Ascii code 136), the Ord() function returns 234 where as I expected it to return 136.

If I run decrypt on the encrypted string, I get a different result than what the original string was, the ê turns into a j.

Can somebody please help on how to solve this?

```
procedure TForm1.btnEncryptClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  sTempString : string;
  iIndex,
  i: integer;
begin
  sTempString  := edtOriginalString.Text ;
  for iIndex := 1 to length(sTempString) do
  begin
    i := ord(sTempString[iIndex]);
    i := i shl 1;
    sTempString[iIndex] := Char(i);
  end;
  edtEncryptedString.Text := sTempString;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnDecryptClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  sTempString : string;
  iIndex,
  i : integer;
begin
  sTempString  := edtEncryptedString.Text ;
  for iIndex := 1 to length(sTempString) do
  begin
    i := ord(sTempString[iIndex]);
    i := i shr 1;
    sTempString[iIndex] := char(i);
  end;
  edtDecryptedString.Text := sTempString;
end;
```

[image: Front-end results]

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using? This is actually important, since Delphi strings are Unicode by default in Delphi 2009 and later.

Comment: This bug was picked up in an old Delphi 6 application

Comment: $EA to $6A (ê to j) means you are loosing the most significant bit. That is because a char is a byte size in D6. You can't use that encryption on characters larger than 127.

Comment: `i := (i shl 1)  + (i shr 7)` for encryption rotates the byte and preserves the msb in the lsb. For decryption, do the opposite.

Answer (score 3):

> If I use the letter ê (Ascii code 136)

No, that's actually wrong. ASCII only has 128 characters (0 to 127).

However, ê is the Unicode character U+00EA: LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH CIRCUMFLEX.

And EA (hex) is indeed 234 (dec).

---

Delphi characters and strings are 8-bit before Delphi 2009, and Unicode in Delphi 2009 and later.

So in your case, Delphi 6, a character is 8-bit.

Hence, your left shift will make you lose the most significant bit (MSB), and you cannot possibly hope to get it back.

Indeed, if we take the case of ê (234), we have

```
1110 1010 (ê)
```

Shifting the bits one step to the left, we obtain

```
1101 0100
```

Shifting the bits one step to the right, we obtain

```
0110 1010 (j).
```

Hence, we lost information.

---

However, your method *will* work for ASCII characters (<= 127), because they all have zero as the MSB. It will *not* work for any characters above 127, because they all have one as the MSB (so it wouldn't work even if `Ord` did indeed return 136 in your case).

---

Hence, you need to abandon or redesign your "encryption" method if you want to support characters above 127. For instance, you could rotate the bits instead of shifting them. Or you could invert them (using `not`).

If you choose to rotate instead of shift, you will get this:

```
1110 1010 (ê)
rotate left:
1101 0101
rotate back (right):
1110 1010 (ê)
```

---

Although it isn't relevant to your actual issue, you might still wonder why `Ord` doesn't return 136 as you'd expect.

Well, before Unicode (mainly in the 1990s and earlier), there simply were many different (non-compatible) character encodings. Often, an 8-bit encoding/codepage (characters 0..255) included the ASCII characters (0..127) and then made its own choices for the remaining characters (128..255). Since ê isn't an ASCII character, this means that only some of these "extended ASCII" codepages might include ê, and among those that do include ê, the actual numeric values might very well differ.

In other words, your source claiming that ê is 136 and your Delphi program are using different 8-bit codepages.

In the modern world of Unicode, this kind of problem no longer exists.

Comment: Ok, so how do I handle the Extended Ascii codes as per http://www.asciitable.com/?

Comment: You don't. You use Unicode. Perhaps UTF-8. And you also need to learn that encryption operates on bytes and not text. Don't expect to encrypt a string directly to a string. The process typically goes like this. 1. Convert plaintext to bytes. 2. Encrypt bytes to more bytes. 3. Convert those bytes to base64 encoded text.

Comment: And of course David is right: this isn't "encryption" at all, only "obfuscation". It is extremely easy to obtain the original plain text from the "encrypted" text.

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/ doesn't seem like a trustworthy resource. There isn't a single "extended ASCII codepage", but many, so the final table is very misleading. That probably isn't even the most common such codepage (likely Windows 1252)! Anyhow, legacy 8-bit codepages shouldn't be used at all today. The text at the top of the page is also inaccurate.